# How to constantly get the touch position?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

I have a code that predicts a shooting path of an arrow in `LateUpdate()`. It is working perfectly on PC and with mouse. Below is the code for when using a mouse:

```
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
        //get the rotation based on the start drag position compared to the current drag position
        zRotation = (Input.mousePosition.y - mouseStart) * (manager.data.sensitivity/15);
        zRotation = Mathf.Clamp(zRotation, -manager.data.maxAimRotation, manager.data.maxAimRotation);
    }
    //reset the rotation if the player is not aiming
    else if((int) zRotation != 0){
        if(zRotation > 0){
            zRotation --;
        }
        else{
            zRotation ++;
        }
    }
```

I want to port this to Android now so am playing around with `Input.Touch`. I changed the above code to the following:

```
 if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                //get the rotation based on the start drag position compared to the current drag position
                zRotation = (Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y) * (manager.data.sensitivity / 15);
                zRotation = Mathf.Clamp(zRotation, -manager.data.maxAimRotation, manager.data.maxAimRotation);
            }
            //reset the rotation if the player is not aiming
            else if ((int)zRotation != 0)
            {
                if (zRotation > 0)
                {
                    zRotation--;
                }
                else
                {
                    zRotation++;
                }
            }
```

But the `zRotation` does not work as it works in mouse. It keeps resetting to the start position after every frame. It almost looks like jittering.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that for mobile controls you are using `Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y`. However, `deltaPosition` gives you the difference between the position on the last **update** compared to the current one. So let's say your app is running at 60 frames per second, it will return the distance per 1/60th of a second. Of course this will be a number close to zero and I believe that is why it looks like it always returns the starting position

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html

You will have to do it similarly to how you did it with your mouse approach. Set a variable `touchStart` on [`Touchphase.Began`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html) and compare it to `touch.position`.

```
float touchStart = 0;

if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) touchStart = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;
                //get the rotation based on the start drag position compared to the current drag position
                zRotation = (Input.GetTouch(0).position.y - touchStart) * (manager.data.sensitivity / 15);
                zRotation = Mathf.Clamp(zRotation, -manager.data.maxAimRotation, manager.data.maxAimRotation);
            }
            //reset the rotation if the player is not aiming
            else if ((int)zRotation != 0)
            {
                if (zRotation > 0)
                {
                    zRotation--;
                }
                else
                {
                    zRotation++;
                }
            }
```

I haven't tested this though, so correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Thanks for replying,. But I tried this before and it did not work. It doesnt even move. When I use ``zRotation = (Input.GetTouch(0).position.y - touchStart)`` The position doesnt move at all. With deltaposition I atleast get some movement but it keeps snapping back to 0.

Comment: Whats happening is the ``else if`` block is activating in every update(). Why does it not stay in the ``if (Input.touchCount > 0)`` block while I am holding the finger down?

Comment: Mmm, can't seem to get it. What happens when you put `Debug.Log(touchStart);` under `if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) touchStart = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;`? Does touchStart have the same value and does it run multiple times or once?

Comment: I managed to fix it. The problem was the I was claculating the ``zrotation`` in ``LateUpdate()`` while setting the ``mouseStart`` position in ``Update()`` every time ``Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began``. I changed this to ``if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began && Input.GetTouch(0).phase != TouchPhase.Moved)`` And it stopped resetting :)